# Scala Multi-Dimensional Arrays not work

Tags: arrays, scala

```
val matrix = Array.ofDim[Int](r,c);
//matrix(0)(0) = 0;

for (i <- 0 to r) {
//println(i)
  for (j <- 0 to c){
    if (j == 0)
      matrix(i)(j) = 1
  }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: eclipse shows a lot of mistakes, it makes no sense to copy them here. it is not so clear as in the VS

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. How are people supposed to help you when they don't know what kind of error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Array has `r` rows and `c` cols, numbered from `0`. You're trying to access an element out of those bounds when `i == r` or `j == c`.

```
for (i <- 0 until r) {
  for (j <- 0 until c) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: the actual values for r and c do not matter. you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception with your code because you use `to` instead of `until`.